# No me funciona el botón de cerrar

Tags: javascript

Abro una ventana pulsando el botón new window y al darle al botón de cerrar debería cerrarse, el problema es que no me funciona no se cierra la ventana que se abre, aquí dejo mi código:

```js
function createWindow() {
    var win = window.open('', 'popup', 'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,resisable=no,srollbars=no,width=800,height=500');
    content = '<input type="button" value="cerrar" onclick="window.opener.done();"/>';
    win.document.write(content);
}
  
function done() {
    document.getElementById('done').text = 'done!';
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <title>ejercicio</title>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/mensaje.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="New window" onclick="createWindow();"/>
        <a id="done"></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

bienvenido a los foros de Stack Overflow en español.

El problema está en que el botón se pinta pero la función onclick no hace lo que debe, ya que la función window.opener.done() nunca se ejecutará.

Para solucionar esto, lo mejor es que, después de pintar el botón con el win.document.write(content), crees el evento onclick después del pintado con la función.

```
function createWindow() {
    var win = window.open('', 'popup', 'status=no,toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,resisable=no,srollbars=no,width=800,height=500');
    content = '<input type="button" id="btnCerrarPopup" value="cerrar" />';
    win.document.write(content);

    win.document.getElementById("btnCerrarPopup").onclick = function cerrarPopup() {
        document.getElementById('done').text = "done!";
        win.close();
    }
}
```

He asignado un id al botón para capturarlo y asignarle el *onclick*. Entonces, la función *cerrarPopup()* lo que hace es, captura el id del elemento "done" de la ventana principal para ponerle un texto y, a continuación, cierro la ventana usando el método "win.close()", ya que *win* es el objeto del popup.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos,